# Vector uses px units but changing the display size value will still change

Tags: vector, android-source

Here is my code

```
<!--
    Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

    You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="32px"
    android:height="32px"
    android:viewportWidth="8"
    android:viewportHeight="8">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M8,0H0v8C0,3.6,3.6,0,8,0z" />

</vector>
```

Every time I change the display size, I will get the drawable again. At this time, my intrinsicWidth and intrinsicHeight are incorrect.

`res.getDrawable(backupDrawableId, null)`

```
       topRoundedDrawable?.let {
            topRoundedSize = Size(it.intrinsicWidth, it.intrinsicHeight)
        }
```

How to make sure to get the correct width and height